# Perl regexp specific letters in string

Tags: regex, perl

input strings consists of letters I N P U Y X

-I have to verify that it only contains these letters and nothing else in PERL regexp

-verify that input also contains at least 2 occurrences of "NP" (without quotes)

example string:

> INPYUXNPININNPXX

strings are all in uppercase

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lookahead based regex in PCRE:

```
^(?=(?:.*?NP){2})[INPUYX]+$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zH3jQ3

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of a line
(?=(?:.*?NP){2}) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
(?:.*?NP){2} Non-capturing group
Quantifier: Exactly 2 times
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
NP matches the characters NP literally (case sensitive)
[INPUYX]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
INPUYX a single character in the list INPUYX literally (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of a line
```

Comment: @r3mus: Thanks for your kind words

Comment: That will technically also allow a trailing newline. Use `\z` instead of `$` to match the spec exactly.

Comment: Yes `\A(?=(?:.*?NP){2})[INPUYX]+\z` will be better choice

Comment: @r3mus, Why match the string twice? I prefer yours. If you don't like the repetition, then you can compose the pattern.

Comment: @ikegami sure, but that wasn't the question that was asked. If OP needs more control, use mine, if not, this is the shortest and most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
^[INPUYX]*NP[INPUYX]*?NP[INPUYX]*$
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/vI2xQ6

Effectively what we're doing here is allowing 0 or more of your character class, capturing the first (required) occurrence of NP, then ensuring that it occurs at least once again before the end of the string.

Hypothetically if you wanted to capture out the middle, you could do:

```
^(?=(?:(.*?)NP){2})[INPUYX]+$
```

Or as @ikegami points out (matching ONLY the single line) `\A(?=(?:(.*?)NP){2})[INPUYX]+\z`.

Comment: works, now i need to set the substring between the 1st NP's as a variable $1 . For the example string "INPYUXNPININNPXX" $1 would be "YUX"

Comment: @user1100752: Not a good idea to ask a bonus question in comments.

Comment: Can't make it variable 1 because the first capture group is being used to verify the existence of the second. I'd use @anabhava's above instead of mine and throw in a capture group: `^(?=(?:(.*?)NP){2})[INPUYX]+$`

Comment: That will technically also allow a trailing newline. Use `\z` instead of `$` to match the spec exactly.

Comment: @user1100752: You can probably use a slight modified answer of mine: `^(?=(?:(.*?)NP){2})[INPUYX]+$` which gives `YUX` in 1st group.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is:

```
/^[INPUXY]*\z/ && /NP.*NP/s
```

---

The following is the most efficient as it avoids matching the string twice and it prevents backtracking on failure:

```
/
   ^
   (?:  (?:[IPUXY]|N[IUXY])* NP  ){2}
   [INPUXY]*
   \z
/x
```

[See in action](http://regex101.com/r/vW5sY5)

---

To capture what's between the two NP, you can use

```
/
   ^
   (?:[IPUXY]|N[IUXY])* NP
   ( (?:[IPUXY]|N[IUXY])* ) NP
   [INPUXY]*
   \z
/x
```

[See in action](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1bY3)